# Why is ExtJs 6.0 Spinnerfield not working ..?

Tags: android, extjs, extjs4

My ExtJs version is 6.0.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        width:300,
        height:300,
        items:
        [
        {
            xtype: 'spinnerfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Test',
            name: 'test',
            minValue: 0,
            allowDecimals: false,
            incrementValue: 1,
            accelerate: true
        }

        ],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

My version is not working ...!

example : [http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/3.4.1.1/examples/spinner/spinner.html]

```
{
    xtype: 'spinnerfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Test',
    name: 'test',
    minValue: 0,
    allowDecimals: false,
    incrementValue: 1,
    accelerate: true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Spinner]

This class is not normally instantiated directly, instead it is subclassed and the `onSpinUp` and `onSpinDown` methods are implemented to handle when the buttons are clicked. A good example of this is the `Ext.form.field.Number` field which uses the spinner to increment and decrement the field's value by its step config value.